# Zencoder: merging and encoding two video files into one

Tags: video, encoding, youtube-api, zencoder

I'm having some difficulty finding documentation on how to merge videos using Zencoder. Here is what I'd like to do:

1. Upload a video to Zencoder for encoding using their api (done)
2. Zencoder merges my two-second branding intro video to the beginning of the uploaded video and encodes them together as a single file
3. Zencoder sends new video off to my youtube account

Are steps 2 & 3 possible with Zencoder. If so, can you link or explain. If not, constructive feedback is welcome.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm looking to do the same thing (sans YouTube).

Comment: did you managed to do anything with the video merging?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your channel, you can achieve no. 3 in two ways. If you're a YouTube partner, you may have access to an SFTP or Aspera account where zencoder can upload to directly.

If that's not possible, you can have zencoder send a notification back to your server when the encoding job is done. This notification will include the URL where you[r server] can fetch the video from and you can use that to push that to YouTube using the YouTube API.

(either way you'll need the zencoder notification, as the SFTP box requires a "delivery.complete" file to be written upon upload completion, and zencoder doesn't do that part)

Haven't found a way to join several videos together in zencoder yet. There's this article: [Video Concatenation? HLS to the Rescue!](http://blog.zencoder.com/2013/01/18/concatenation-hls-to-the-rescue/) - but either I don't get it, or it's not what we're looking for.